# BeautifulSoup returns No Data Recorded when getting table from web

Tags: python, web-scraping, html-table, beautifulsoup

New to web scraping.

I need to get the **Daily Observations table**(the long table at the end of the page) data from the page:

https://www.wunderground.com/history/daily/us/tx/greenville/KGVT/date/2015-01-05?cm_ven=localwx_history

The html of the table starts from `<table _ngcontent-c16="" class="tablesaw-sortable" id="history-observation-table">`

My code is:

```
url = "https://www.wunderground.com/history/daily/us/tx/greenville/KGVT/date/2015-01-05?cm_ven=localwx_history"
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
soup.findAll(class_="region-content-observation")
```

And the output is:

```
[<div class="region-content-observation">
 <city-history-observation _nghost-c34=""><div _ngcontent-c34="">
 <div _ngcontent-c34="" class="observation-title">Daily Observations</div>
 <!-- -->
     No Data Recorded

   <!-- -->
 </div></city-history-observation>
 </div>]
```

So it's not getting the table and returned No Data Recorded, but it did get the title.

And When I tried

```
soup.findAll(class_="tablesaw-sortable")
```

or

```
soup.findAll('tr')
```

it only returned empty list.

Does anyone know where went wrong?

Comment: Is the table JS generated?

Comment: There is no `history-observation-table` in page source. It's generated dynamically, so you cannot get it with simple HTTP request

Comment: Yes I think it is JS

Comment: Do you know what to do in this case? @Andersson

Comment: You can try tool that supports JavaScript handling (like Selenium, python-HTML. pyQt, etc...) or check which XHR request responsible for Observation table delivery and make direct API request

Comment: I've had good luck with Selenium, pretty easy to use.

Comment: Okay, I will try Selenium. Thanks! @Andersson

Comment: I will try it, thanks! @SuperStew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open the web page in Firefox, you can use the *Network* tab from its *Developer Tools* to see all the different web resources that are downloaded.  The data you are interested in is actually provided by [this JSON file](https://api.weather.com/v1/geocode/33.06777954/-96.0652771/observations/historical.json?apiKey=6532d6454b8aa370768e63d6ba5a832e&startDate=20150105&endDate=20150105&units=e) – which can be retrieved and then parsed using Python’s [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html) library.

Note: I’ve never scraped a site that uses API keys so I’m not sure about the ethics or best practice in this situation. As a test, I was able to download the JSON file without any problems. However, I suspect Weather Underground wouldn’t want you using their key too many times – and it looks like they [no longer provide free weather API keys](https://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/).

Comment: Just tried your method. It is an interesting and fast way to get it done! But I am worried about the API issue too. Anyway, thanks for providing a new solution!